# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException Without use db

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have integrated Bugsense on some of my apps, and I got today two crashes in two apps (**But I don´t use any db on this apps**) the next output :

```
Error Message

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error

Where

SQLiteStatement.java:61

**Short Stacktrace**
0   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
1   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
2   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
3   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1950)
4   at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.removeCache(WebViewDatabase.java:832)
5   at android.webkit.CacheManager.getCacheFile(CacheManager.java:352)
Tag
external_crash
```

Why my pagages has this error, if I don´t use Sqlite?

Comment: this db is the db used by the WebView. You can't really do anything about that. Are you doing cache operations on the webview at some point?

Comment: Hi @njzk2, yes I have cache enabled. mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebView uses an internal SQLite database to manage its cache.

That database got an I/O error from the disk, which means that the flash storage on that device is flaky.